# Receive broadcast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tested a code to receive a broadcast message but it's not working. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class SendReceiveRoomName : MonoBehaviour
{
    const int PORT_NO = 15000;
    private readonly UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
    IPEndPoint ipendpointSend = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), PORT_NO);
    IPEndPoint ipendpointReceive = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO);
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartListening();
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        asyncResult = udpClient.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }

    private void Receive(IAsyncResult asr)
    {
        ipendpointReceive = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO);
        byte[] bytes = udpClient.EndReceive(asr, ref ipendpointReceive);
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        Debug.Log("Received message:" + message);
        StartListening();
    }
}
```

This script is attached to gameobject. Can someone point to me where is the problem

Comment: Please expand on "it's not working". What exactly is not working? are there any errors, what should it do, what is it that it doesn't do. Are there things it does do?

Comment: @Remy_rm It's not receiving a broadcast message coming from other device